# Why all my requests are blocked until async/await method executed

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, model-view-controller, async-await, action

I have an asp.net mvc async method waiting for 10 second.
The problem is IIS Express (production IIS also) stops processing incoming requests until that async method finishes.
I thought await keyword frees current thread for new incoming request. But it seems that I missed something.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AsyncMethod()
{
    using (DeliveryPortalEntities context = new DeliveryPortalEntities())
    {
        await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'");
    }
    return Json(new { status = "ok" });
}
```

**Update! Can anyone explain why during this code execution IIS stops answer requests immediately.**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AsyncMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(10000).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: "stops processing incoming requests until that async method finishes" how do you know this?

Comment: @Ian Kemp, all requests from other tabs frozen for 10 seconds.

Comment: the user who executes the awaitable task must wait because that is what await does. if another user is doing something at the same time, a thread could be awailable to do whatever he needs to do because the first user is not blocking the throughput with his actions. Chances are, you are the first user and there is nothing else to do for IIS

Comment: @Johan Herstad, thank you so much.

Comment: Are you using session state? The use of session state serializes requests because only one request can use the session state at a time.

Comment: @Paulo Morgado, yes, I store user roles in Session, but I can't figure out how this can influence on parallel requests execution. I simply request AsyncMethod from my browser and bang... every simultaneous requests stops until AsyncMethod finishes its work.

Comment: There can only be one HTTP request accessing the session state at a time. Other requests will have to wait until the state has been released. Does the same happen with different users? Or sessions?

Comment: @Paulo Morgado, SessionState was the case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought await keyword frees current thread for new incoming request.

It does; the thread is free. However, the request is not complete. And if that request has a read/write lock on the session, then no other requests for that session can be processed until that lock is free.

To resolve this, you'll need to change your session usage. If you can go sessionless, that's best - it allows really good horizontal scalability. If not, try to go read-only. Long requests with a read-only session lock can run concurrently with other requests in that same session if they also only need a read-only session lock.

Comment: Stephen, I added [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)] to my async controller and now everything works fine. Thanks